# What is the size factor between http and real world data ?

Tags: http

My apache server logs the size of the response and when I sum it I get 25Mo/month.
I have also an embedded software that connects to this server through gsm. My internet service provider tells me I am using 250Mo/month on this machine, which solely connects to the apache server.

So is there a 10x factor between the upper layer in the http protocol and the lowest layer ? I would believe a factor 2 because of http headers not counted in apache logs, handshakes, lost packets, etc. but this much ?

Comment: I believe there is a lot more going on than just your packets being encapsulated.. I'm not a network expert but there's also stuff like handshakes, etc... Since tcp has a 3-way handshake, theres a lot more packets being sent than just the data packets you are logging...

Comment: that's why Im asking if you guys have seen something similar and if you have some numbers at hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server sends something and says it is 2.7ko, then with packets sniffer tools I saw that the client will receive ~3ko, so the size factor is approximately +10%. Of course I believe it can vary for bigger http bodies (1Mo)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that one of the numbers is in bits and the other in bytes...  (8x ~ 10x)

Comment: :) I have checked that and it is not

Comment: Does that make the answer worth a click?  ;)